# Is there a graph library for Burtin’s Antibiotics sample in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, graph, visualization

I have a sample data that I want to visualize by a graph like this in React Js:

[image: Burtin’s Antibiotics Protovis]

And this is the link to the JavaScript code: 
[Burtin’s Antibiotics Protovis](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/antibiotics-burtin.html)

Does anyone has any idea that which React graph library I can use for having exactly this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The library that this example is taken from is deprecated:

> Protovis is no longer under active development.
>
> The final release of Protovis was v3.3.1 (4.7 MB). The Protovis team
>   is now developing a new visualization library, D3.js, with improved
>   support for animation and interaction. D3 builds on many of the
>   concepts in Protovis; for more details, please read the introduction
>   and browse the examples.

So you should continue your investigations into D3 and React. Here is an article about it: https://medium.com/turo-engineering/react-meets-d3-6a40881d0d73

> When one talks about rendering charts or any kind of data
>   visualization in the web, D3.js is the de facto standard. So, if we
>   want to build beautiful and reusable charts, we should definitely
>   leverage the power of D3.
>
> How do we integrate it? But we have a problem, our web client is built
>   in React and this library doesn’t get along well with D3: both use
>   very different approaches to update the DOM. While React uses a
>   virtual DOM and a well defined lifecycle to calculate and optimize DOM
>   updates, D3 uses the browser DOM and data attributes.
>
> If we want to build nice charts, with neat animations and don’t have
>   our heads burst when dealing with SVG elements and their positioning,
>   using D3 is a must, so we need to find a way so these two libraries
>   can play well together.

Comment: Thank you, Yes, It's deprecated, I'll look at the article.